# ModelMapper: Mix implicit and explicit mapping?

Tags: java, modelmapper

In order to write the minimum amount of code required, I'm trying to let ModelMapper generate its implicit mapping and only write explicit property mappings for those properties that it couldn't auto-map.

If I let ModelMapper generate an implicit mapping using:

```
modelMapper.createTypeMap(SourceType.class, DestType.class);
```

it complains about `setSomeId` having multiple possible mappings. I then tried to fix just that using:

```
modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<SourceType, DestType>() {
    protected void configure() {
        map().setSomeId(source.getProperty().getWeirdID());
    }
});
```

However, I found that ModelMapper still complains, because an exception is actually thrown on `createTypeMap`, so it doesn't have a chance to reach my custom mapping code.

If I invert both statements, I get an error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: A TypeMap already exists for class SourceType and class DestType

If I leave out `createTypeMap` completely, ModelMapper complains about missing mappings for all other properties of the `DestType` (those who it was able to map automatically with `createTypeMap`).

I found no explicit clue in the Documentation whether mixing implicit with explicit mappings is supported and how it's done.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ModelMapper.createTypeMap` try `ModelMapper.addMappings` (first). This still creates (and returns) a `TypeMap`, but takes your `PropertyMap` into account while doing so.

Comment: As mentioned in the original post, I already tried inverting both statements and also leaving out `createTypeMap` completely. Unfortunately, that didn't lead to the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is still an issue to you, and I must admit I am new to ModelMapper. Never the less I have struggled with the same issue you have/had. I seem to have solved it.

```
    TypeMap<RateDTO, Rate> rateDTORateTypeMap = modelMapper.getTypeMap(RateDTO.class, Rate.class);
    if(rateDTORateTypeMap == null) {
        rateDTORateTypeMap = modelMapper.createTypeMap(RateDTO.class, Rate.class);
    }
    rateDTORateTypeMap.setProvider(request -> {
        RateDTO source = RateDTO.class.cast(request.getSource());
        CurrencyAndAmount price = new CurrencyAndAmount(source.getPrice().getCurrencyCode(), source.getPrice().getAmount());
        return new Rate(price, source.getPaymentDate(), source.getPaymentId());
    });
```

Basically I first try and get the TypeMap if its already there, otherwise I create a new/modified mapping.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we want to map `Source source` to `Destination destination`.
Instead of

```
Destination destination = modelMapper.map(source, Destination.class);
```

In order to combine explicit and implicit mappings we nedd to add `implicitMappings()` in `TypeMap`

```
public Destination mapSourceToDestination(Source source) {
            TypeMap<Source, Destination> typeMap = modelMapper
                    .typeMap(Source.class, Destination.class)
                    .implicitMappings()
                    .addMappings(mapper -> {
                        mapper.map(source -> source.getPropetryOne().getSubPropetryOne(), Destination::setPropetryA);
                    });
            return typeMap.map(source);
        }
```